# Powershell Remoting unable to use remote cmdlets

Tags: powershell

**Goal:**

I am attempting to write a script that would automate implicit remoting for 100 or more users daily.

I am following this tutorial by Don Jones;
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff720181.aspx

**Problem:**

I am getting an error after entering my custom cmdlets, for example:

```
PS > cmdlet1 FooBar
d : The term 'cmdlet1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ cmdlet1 FooBar
+ ~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (d:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

**My script:**

```
Set-Alias -Name gm -Value Get-TheModules -Description 'Grabs The Modules'
function Get-TheModules
{ 
  $ServerARM = New-PSSession -ComputerName serverA -Authentication Kerberos
  # Import Modules
  Write-Verbose -Message 'Importing Custom modules...'
  Invoke-command -ScriptBlock { import-module -Name 'Z:\Modules\ModuleA' } -Session $ServerARM
  Invoke-command -ScriptBlock { import-module -Name 'Z:\Modules\ModuleB' } -Session $ServerARM
  Invoke-command -ScriptBlock { import-module -Name 'Z:\Modules\ModuleC' } -Session $ServerARM
  Export-PSSession -Session $ServerARM -commandname *Cmdlet1,Cmdlet2,Cmdlet3* -OutputModule 'CustomCMDlets' -Force -AllowClobber
  Remove-PSSession -Session $ServerARM
  Import-Module CustomMods -prefix CRem
  Write-Verbose -Message 'Custom modules successfully imported...'
}
```

**Results from running script:**

```
PS> GM

    Directory: Z:\Users\-\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\CustomCMDlets


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        1/16/2017   1:57 PM             99 CustomCMDlets.format.ps1xml
-a----        1/16/2017   1:57 PM            801 CustomCMDlets.psd1
-a----        1/16/2017   1:57 PM          41584 CustomCMDlets.psm1

Custom modules successfully imported...
```

**Question:**

Given my goal and problem, what am I not understanding about the article, where is there an issue in my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your function's name is `Cmdlet1` but you import it with `Import-Module -Prefix CRem`, then the name of the  imported function will be `CRemCmdlet1`.

If the function were named with proper `Verb-Noun` syntax, the prefix would be placed before the noun, so if the name were `Invoke-Cmdlet1` then when imported with prefix it will be `Invoke-CRemCmdlet1`.

Comment: It is as you said, I was confused with my Verb-Noun Syntax by placing my prefix with the verb. Thanks this did the trick